# Touchpad not working in fedora

Tags: linux, drivers

I have cracked version of windows 8.1 in my laptop and now have dual booted it (windows 8.1 and fedora ). My touch pad in laptop works fine in windows but when started laptop using fedora, touchpad doesn't work.
To make touchpad work can I downlaod drivers. If yes, please give me a link for it and if no, what should be done?

Comment: What brand and model do you own?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look and see if you have this driver installed.

in ubuntu its called - xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic - Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server

and in general the touchpad drive is called 'synaptics'..

**Try see if its installed**

```
yum update -y
yum search synaptics
```

then install the driver using.

```
yum install package_name
```

If it is and still not works... See this link to see if its enabled. (http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Synaptics_TouchPad_driver_for_X)

Answer (score 0):

****Solution 1:****

I) Hold '**Alt+F2**' ,a command dialog shall pop up.

II) Type '**r**' and hit enter

This will restart your desktop environment, it will take a while and then, your mouse should be working fine.
If you get a message that says:

> *'Restart is not available on Wayland'*

then press '**Esc**' and proceed to *Solution 2*

****Solution 2:****

I) Open the Terminal by pressing  '**Ctrl + Alt + T**' together.

II) Open the Grub file by using:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

III) It will then ask for your password, enter it and continue.

IV) A text editor will open up and you need to edit this line

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8"

into

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux i8024.noloop"

V) Save it using '**Ctrl + S**' and update the grub file, using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

VI) Shutdown using

```
sudo shutdown now
```

Start the computer again and your mouse should finally work.